# Function composition in MapReduce

Tags: java, algorithm, math, hadoop, mapreduce

Let's say we have 2 files f1 and f2 whose key-value pairs represent functions in the mathematical sense. What is the simplest way to find their composition using MapReduce? What is the most efficient way?

For example, given:

```
f1
a -> b
x -> y
s -> t

f2
b -> c
t -> r

f1 . f2 (composition of f1 and f2) would be
a -> c
s -> r
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Invert `f1` to `f1'`
2. Map reduce over `f1'` and `f2` simultaneously. For each `x->v2` in `f2`, and for all `x->k1` in `f1'` (if any), output `k1->v2`.

This will only work if `f1` has a reasonably large range. If too many `k1` map to the same `v1`, then the corresponding map worker will be swamped.

Comment: In step 1 you can only invert f1. How can you do it by inverting f2?